# Why am i getting a segmentation fault using scanf? I've initialized and set memory size, but still getting seg fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, scanf, c-strings, isalpha

Noob question, probably. I've looked through other answers, and I've tried what they've done. But I'm still getting the error every time. This is the first snippet from my caesar cipher program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char message[81];
    char cipher[81];
    
    do
    {
        printf("Enter a message: ");
        scanf("%[^\n]", &message); 
      //scanf("%s", &message) = error as well
        printf("Test"); //to see if it prints. doesn't print, so seg fault must be on above line
        if (!isalpha(message))
        {
            printf("Invalid input. Enter only letters.\n");
        }
        else
        {
            valid = 1;
        }
    } while (valid == 0);

// ...
```

As input, I will enter anything - a string, one char, a number, etc, and I still get a seg fault.

I'm compiling my code with -W -Wall -ansi -pedantic , and I'm getting no errors or warnings related to the seg fault.

Comment: Please post [mcve]. Pretty sure though that you *are* getting some warnings, on line `scanf("%[^\n]", &message);` at the very least, as it should be `scanf("%[^\n]", message);`

Answer (score 2):

For starters the type of the argument in this call

```
scanf("%[^\n]", &message);
```

is invalid. You need to write

```
scanf("%[^\n]", message);
```

Also you need to remove the new line character '\n' from the input buffer before the next call of scanf.

The function `isalpha` expects an object of the type `char`. But you are passing an expression of the type `char *`.

```
if (!isalpha(message))
```

that invokes undefined behavior.

Also a question arises to your code snippet where the variable `valid` is declared.

If you want to check whether a string contains alpha symbols or/and maybe white spaces then you need to check all symbols of the entered string.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int all_letters( const char *s )
{
    while ( *s && isalpha( ( unsigned char )*s  ) ) ++s;
    
    return *s == '\0';
}

int main(void) 
{
    char message[81];
    int valid = 0;
    
    do
    {
        printf( "Enter a message: " );
        scanf( "%80[^\n]", message );
        while ( getchar() != '\n' );
        
        valid = all_letters( message );
        
        if ( !valid )
        {
            printf( "Invalid input. Enter only letters.\n" );
        }
    } while ( !valid );
    
    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Enter a message: 123
Invalid input. Enter only letters.
Enter a message: Hello
```

Comment: Any idea why this call to `isalpha` compiles? Doesn't C warn about implicit conversions from pointers to `int`?

Comment: @templatetypedef  I think the compiler issues a warning.

Comment: Nitpick: `isalpha` expects an int

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Compiling this locally with `-Wall -Werror` doesn't complain on that line, which really surprised me.

Comment: @templatetypedef It might be defined like `#define isalpha(x)  _isalpha_table[(unsigned char)(x)]`   and some compilers take measures to suppress warnings generated by system headers.  I would guess that writing `(isalpha)(message)` would make the diagnostic appear

Comment: @M.M Oh, huh. That would definitely do it.

Comment: @M.M and that's why macros are evil.

Answer (score 0):

I ran this code under `valgrind` and the error is actually at this line here:

```
if (!isalpha(message))
```

Remember that `isalpha` takes in a `char` (technically an `int`, but it's expected to just hold a single character). By passing in `message`, you're passing in a `char [81]`, which isn't of the right type.

What mystifies me is why this compiles and runs at all, even with the warning level cranked up to the maximum, since there's no implicit conversion from a `char [81]` to a single `char`.

To fix this, you'll need to change the code you've written here so that it more explicitly tests that all the characters entered are letters. You may also want to check the return value from `scanf` to make sure that it doesn't fail and to clear the invalid characters from `stdin` in the event that it fails.

Comment: There is nothing in this code that would prevent compilation (except it being incomplete). But it should be giving a bunch of warnings that the OP seem to be ignoring as considering them *"not related to the seg fault."*

Comment: Nitpick: `isalpha` expects an int

Comment: @EugeneSh. It's been a while since I did straight C coding, but don't C compilers warn about implicitly converting pointers to integers?

Comment: @templatetypedef Yep, weird, but it does not warn for me too, I would expect it to do though. Probably there is some extra switch to be turned on

Comment: In fact, it did not on Wandbox online compiler, but it does warn on my local gcc 10.3.0: *warning: passing argument 1 of 'isalpha' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]*

Comment: So `isalpha` is probably being passed an integer that's way outside the bounds of what it's expecting, but why does that make it crash?

Comment: @MarkRansom Some implementations of `isalpha` do table-driven lookups based on the provided integer and expect the integer to hold a single `char` value. It's possible that the implementation is indexing out of bounds when using the pointer value (likely not something that fits in a char), but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: I was wondering why it would resort to table-based lookup when a single `if` would suffice, but I found some documentation that suggests it's locale aware.

Comment: It's not just a "nitpick" that `isalpha` takes an `int`: the value is expected to be in the range of `unsigned char`, not `char`. It's also a mistake to pass a plain char; if the plain char is negative then the lookup table can look out of bounds.  Some compilers are nice and guard against this but they're not required to